# Reset client token accidentally , change back?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I have a huge problem, I reset the client token and it generated a new token. Because I can't build our iOS and Android apps quickly, how do I insert my old client token back?!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t think you can insert a value manually.

Comment: You can't indeed, which is strange because now my iOS and Android apps may have problems. Now I need to rebuild them both, get them approved, push updates to users and hope they update. Really doesn't make sence Facebook!!!

Comment: Well what made little sense here rather seems to be that you did reset it in the first place.

Comment: True, but I'd expected to get a fill your own code textfield but there is not.

Comment: Of course there isn’t - that value is supposed to be as random as possible, and so naturally Facebook doesn’t want developers to be able to compromise security by inputting “abc” or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User tokens are valid for 2 hours only. Extended User Tokens are valid for 60 days. You can´t just reuse an old Token.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

**Edit: My bad, you are talking about the Client Token, which can be changed in the App settings. Afaik you can´t just set an old one, you can only reset it to get a new one.**

Comment: The client token is a different thing, it‘s not a user access token.